# pass value attribute from view to controller asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, razor, view, asp.net-core, controller

here was my code from view

```
@{ var companies = (IEnumerable<Company>)ViewData["companylist"]; }
@foreach (var item in companies)
{
    //post the form to upload actions, index2 for testing
       <form id="submitfinal" method="post" asp-action="Upload" asp-controller="report" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="companyid" value="@item.Id" />
            @item.Name (@item.Status)

            <input type="file" name="files" />
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="upload final report" />

    </form>

}
```

Question here was how can i take the data from input tag attribute to controller?
let say the @item.Id is 1234, how i get that in controller?

Comment: In the ViewModel (or in function arguments) for the controller's method `ReportController.Upload` which handles the POST request, called when user submits the form. Can I suggest to follow an ASP.NET Core tutorial? It will introduce this _concept_ in the easy way.

Comment: how exactly i can get the value of input tag's attribute data in controller?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-controller

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti this is not the answer i want

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(ICollection<IFormFile> files, FormCollection form)
        {var inputForm = form["inputForm"];}
let say this is how to get the form, but i am wanting the data from the <input> value attribute

Comment: Did you read the linked tutorial? It's exactly accepting parameters (as for files they're arguments for your function or properties in the VM built by ASP.NET MVC runtime and passed as...argument). We might write a 30 lines answer but everything is already in docs (really!). Don't try to solve _problems_ one by one before you went through the basics.

Comment: What exactly you want? Get a particular model property value on postback or you want a value in post?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.yourPropertyname)
```

or using jquery ajax you can send the value to controller.

Comment: how i get that in controller?

Comment: OP already has this in her code (just different form), she is asking for another (trivial) thing which is how to get back that value in the controller method invoked on POST.

Comment: This is what you need i think. same question..
[link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124324/submitting-form-and-pass-data-to-controller-method-of-type-filestreamresult)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late, but I would use asp-route-Id like:

```
<form id="submitfinal" method="post" asp-route-Id="@item.Id" asp-action="Upload" asp-controller="report" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```